# Global Array/List. Class? Handler? Copy and Paste?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, global-variables

I need to make a global ArrayList or Array for the entire project.

I have an asp.net C# project. I am loading data from a database

The thing is I need the data to be used in multiple pages.
Rather than copy the code and paste it in all pages, is there a way to make a global code?

I know of making a public static class and calling it from other pages. And I know not much is truly global.

But what about classes? Or .ascx? Handler?

What can be used and which is better?

Or must I just copy and paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the data in Application variable. Static class is not a better option in case of web application. To set the data in Application variable

```
Application.Add("Key", data);
```

To get the data

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["Key"];
```

Comment: Application cache is available to all users and lives until IIS is reset or memory recycles the ASP.NET process. If you want everyone using the app to have access to this list of data, then use this solution.

Comment: @djs .. you are right. But its a better to use Application rather than static class.

Comment: I prefer static classes.  The code seems cleaner and more type safe.  Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session cache to store your list of information. This will make the data available to multiple pages as it is sitting in memory. Since each user has their own version of Session cache, this solution will not allow the same data to be shared among all users of the system; Application cache handles that scenario.

I would also suggest using `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`, as `List<T>` is type safe.